# Metro bundler not starting automatically with expo start

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo to develop a react native app on Windows 10.

When I run `expo start` the Metro Builder starts automatically only if disconnected from the internet and with the `--offline` switch. When connected the `--offline` switch is useless.

This is the console output, there are no errors or warnings (the same is true for `expo start --offline`):

```
expo start
Starting project at C:\Users\xxx\Projects\my-reactnative-project
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
```

The output in the browser is:
[image: Metro browser output]

There are no QR code, no link, pressing `Tunnel`, `LAN` or `Local` makes no difference.

I tried reinstalling `expo-cli` but the problem is still there. This is the output of `expo diagnostics`:

```
  Expo CLI 3.13.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.11.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.11.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.3.0.0 AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~36.0.0 => 36.0.2
      react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz => 0.61.4
```

Do you know how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happened to me too. It has been working until yesterday when it suddenly stopped working with no apparent reason. You can try reinstalling expo-cli, or try another version, or try on another computer.

Answer (score 4):

deleting the metro modules from node_modules , and running `npm install` worked for me .

Comment: It works for me too, thanks! It just happen that after installing other library, in my case `react-navigation`, the `metro` related libraries are broken. So reinstalling them is the most logical explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall expo cli, run `npm cache clean -- force` and run `expo start -c` or `expo start`

If it does not work, keep trying, worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, 
I uninstalled expo-cli using npm -g uninstall expo-cli,
installed it again and now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Things that might fix it that worked for me:

- npm audit fix
- If on expo start some packages are incompatible
- install those packages with "expo install ..."
- Try in another network as it might be just a network issue
- Use the expo tunnel instead of lan

Answer (score 1):

It may be a firewall issue. You can force the bundler to run on a different port (i chose 3000).

$ expo start --port 3000